# Calculate divergence via partial derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, vector-fields

I need to calculate the divergence and curl for a vectorfield. I've done that before so that's no problem :) Or I've done it using partial derivative, maybe there are multiple ways to solve for divergence.

My vector field is $\vec{E} = \vec{A} \sin\big( \vec{a} \cdot \vec{r} \big)$

My problem is that I don't understand how I find my $x$, $y$ and $z$ components. Or do you substitute the mentioned components for $A$, $a$ and $r$. If so, what is the motivation behind that?

Comment: Hint: $a\cdot r=a_x x+a_y y+a_z z$, $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$, so...

Comment: How is this supposed to be a physics question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a certain way that vector calculus operators convert to other coordinate systems from Cartesian. The derivations are a little bit involved but it is a common practice to straight away use the formula. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates for those formula. Alternatively you can do it using tensor(index) notation.

Answer (score 0):

The divergence of a vector field is a scalar,  which means that when evaluated in another coordinate system, you obtain the same value. This means that you can evaluate the divergence of the expression in the coordinate system which has its $x$-axis pointing in the direction of the vector $\vec{a}$. In that coordinate system, you have:

$$\vec{E} = \vec{A}\sin(a x)$$

where $a = |\vec{a}|$. The divergence is thus:

$$\nabla\cdot \vec{E} = a A_x\cos(a x)$$

This expression is only valid in the special coordinate system we've chosen. But we can write $a A_x = \vec{a}\cdot \vec{A}$ and $a x = \vec{a}\cdot \vec{r}$.  So, the general expression is:

$$\nabla\cdot \vec{E} =\vec{a}\cdot \vec{A}\cos(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{r})$$

The curl can be evaluated in the same way. In the same special coordinates you can see immediately without doing any computations that it is the zero vector. But being a vector means that it transforms as a vector under rotations, it is therefore zero in any arbitrary coordinate system:

$$\nabla\times \vec{E} = \vec{0}$$